# Assume that $a \implies \text{false}$. What does that imply about $a$?

Tags: propositional-calculus

The title says most of it. I've recently started learning logical implications, and in my homework I stumbled upon a task that states that,

> Assume that $a\implies\text{false}$. What does that imply about $a$?

I tried looking up this problem online, but could not find an explanation about a way solve it, could someone help me?

Comment: if a is false, the implication is true. if a is true, the implication is false.

Comment: We can translate this into mathematical notation as: $a \implies 0 = a'+0 = a'$. So $a$ is false. Another way to look at it is: true cannot imply false.

Comment: Normally, we have $A\implies B$ and $A,B$ have values true or false. So, I guess it is meant that $B$ is false. If $A\implies B$ is true, then $A$ cannot be true, so $A$ must be false.

Comment: "stumbled upon"?  Does that mean you didn't read the chapter before looking at the problems?  In constructive logic, "$a \implies \bot$" is equivalent to $\lnot a$.

Comment: @DanielV we were only given brief overview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement implies that $a$ is false.

The basic mathematical concept at play here is *contradiction*. If you assume something, and get a contradiction ("false" is a generic name for a contradiction), then that thing must have been false in the first place. So if $a \implies \text{false}$, then assuming $a$ was true we got a contradiction; therefore, $a$ must not have been true. So we conclude that $a$ is false.

Sometimes, the definition of "not $a$" is taken to be "$a \implies \text{false}$"; the above reasoning shows that this definition makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

It's like the saying: "if *that* is true, then pigs fly!", by which we of course mean that we believe the *that* is not true. So in your logic expression, the $a$ is like the 'that', while the $false$ is the 'pigs fly'. So the logic expression, like this saying, is the same as saying that $a$ is false.

Answer (score 1):

$$p \to \text{False} \equiv \neg p \lor \text{False} \equiv \neg p$$

Answer (score 0):

For any mathematical statements $A$ and $B$, we have $A\implies B$ if and only if $A$ is false or $B$ is true. For our problem we have $A\equiv a$ and $B\equiv\text{FALSE}$. Since $B$ is $\text{FALSE}$, the only way the implication $A\implies B$ can be true is that $A$ must be false. Thus we can infer that $a$ is false.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to propositional logic, students often get caught up in the details and forget the meanings - which is unfortunate, because if you can think clearly about the meanings behind the sentences you're working with, the answer is often obvious. "$a \implies \mathrm{false}$" says, literally, "if $a$ is true, then false is true". "False is true" is nonsense - it's something we know to be false. If I tell you "if it's raining outside then the moon is made of green cheese", what can you conclude about the weather? If it *were* raining, then the moon would be made of green cheese. Since the moon is not made of any sort of dairy product, this is clearly an impossible state of affairs - so it must not be raining. Likewise, if we know $a \implies \mathrm{false}$, then we can conclude that $a$ is false.